# mvc5 Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Action'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I get:

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'Action'
```

excepiton in my "_ExternalLoginsListPartial" view but I don't understand why because in Login view I call:

```
@Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", new { Action = "ExternalLogin", ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
```

And when I look into the Model in debugger it definaltely contains "Action".

[image]

Can anyone help me understand that?
Actually my site was running but today I started to edit "ManageUserViewModel" so that I can store some user specific settings in it. After that I always get this exception although I already reverted my changes...

The code below makes my website run again:

```
  //string action = Model.Action;
    //string returnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl;
    string action = "ExternalLogin";
    string returnUrl = "/myTime/en/Manage";


    using (Html.BeginForm(action, "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div id="socialLoginList">
            <p>
                @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders)
                {
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType" title="Log in using your @p.Caption account">@p.AuthenticationType</button>
                }
            </p>
        </div>
    }
```

UPDATE:
I'm able to reproducte the problem. As mentioned above I tried to change "ManageUserViewModel" so that the user can set some settings. Since I only use Google login I removed the password stuff for the model. To reproduce the exception comment out everything in ManageUserViewModel (make it an empty class).
Then comment out everything in Manage:

```
 //
    // POST: /Account/Manage
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Manage(ManageUserViewModel model)
    {


        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

and then comment in:

```
  app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
```

in StartupAuth.cs

And you get the exception when you click the google login button.
You can use the default MVC5 template and just do the steps described above to reproduce this...

I'm not sure if it is the wrong place to let my user store his settings. However, the screenshot below is definately giving me wrong information...

UPDATE2:
You don't have to edit Manage function in AccountController. It is enough to make “ManageUserViewModel” empty.

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: Is the type of your model defined in the partial view? Can you send the whole partial view code? But I would create a class model though and pass it to the partial instead of anonymous object, that will work 100%.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the issue. Please see my UPDATE in my post.

Comment: I still don't see how the type of your model is defined in your partial view. And is it defined at all? usually it is defined at the top of your view as @model ModelType.

Comment: I don't modified “_ExternalLoginsListPartial.cshtml” so it is the same file as generated from the MVC5 project template. This file does not contain a Model type definition and in the cshtml-code that renders this view (“Login.cshtml”) an anonymous type is used(new { Action = "ExternalLogin") . You can perform the three steps described in my question on the MVC5 Visual Studio Project template and you will get the error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that it exists in the debugger is meaningless. The debugger exposes the object and all it's properties without knowing or caring about it's type. The problem you're having in your view is that you don't have a model definition, and because of that, your "model" is an `object`. The `Object` type truly does not have a property or method named `Action`, so you get the error.

The best solution is to simply specify your model as the actual type you're working with. Then you get intellisense and all the other goodness that comes from being strongly-typed. The alternative, is to cast `Model` to `dynamic`, but that's really nasty.

Comment: This makes absolutely sense but why does this exception only occur when I make "ManageUserViewModel" empty? And why is it working in the template Microsoft delivers with Visual Studio? They are using an anonymous type in Login.cshtml -> new { Action = "ExternalLogin", ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }...

Comment: This reply makes perfect sense, but does nothing to resolve the issue.  What type should model be??  Out of the box, _ExternalLoginsListPartial does not define a model, nor does Login.cshtml, which simply passes an annonymous object. There's something else going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exact error on this exact line because I had enabled Twitter as an authorization source with **bogus key and secret values**.

[image]

When I **commented that section out in StartupAuth.cs**, the application worked as expected.

Comment: I still don't understand why this is happening. However, the answer from Chris -> "The best solution is to simply specify your model as the actual type you're working with" solved the issue..